# System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'All' was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, xamarin, entity-framework-core, uno-platform

In the process of updating one of my NuGet packages, I ran into a runtime exception when running the application on a physical iOS device.

The app in question is a Uno Platform app, and contains a subproject for processing an iOS intent.

Both the iOS and intents project are using

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.7
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 5.0.7

#### Stack Trace

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethods' threw an exception. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'All' was not present in the dictionary.
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].get_Item (TKey key) [0x0001e] in <da8885cdf78b449d96de00cdb9d47225>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethods.<.cctor>g__GetMethod|185_58 (System.String name, System.Int32 genericParameterCount, System.Func`2[T,TResult] parameterGenerator, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethods+<>c__DisplayClass185_0& ) [0x00014] in <4d1f22249bbe4676a871766038953138>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethods..cctor () [0x00052] in <4d1f22249bbe4676a871766038953138>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryableMethodNormalizingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall (System.Linq.Expressions.M<…>
```

It seems like the EFCore library is unable to process the 'All' method on my collection since it has not been loaded in the internal dictionary. I'm looking for guidance on where and how this dictionary is being build so I know where to look to fix this issue.

Comment: This question is reported as an issue on efcore github here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25182

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem as well; it happened only with Release builds, not with Debug builds. That's usually a sign of the linker being a bit too active.

As @michaldivis said [here on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25182#issuecomment-1061587944), adding `--linkskip=System.Core` to the build arguments worked for me. Make sure you set the right configuration and platform.

[image]